# Can Lighbox jQuery Plugin run in an HTML email?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, lightbox2

I have some images on a site, and have the lighbox plugin working - so when you click on an image, it opens up the image in a frame, and lets you scroll through the rest of the images on the page, very elegantly.

I've been asked by someone, is it possible to have the lighbox plugin work from within an HTML email?

I suspect not, as I don't think emails carry JavaScript code - but can anyone confirm if it definitely isn't possible?

Thank you

Comment: i dont think so, but might be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not run JavaScript in an email client. There would be very large security issues with this.

Answer (score 1):

Email clients are very restrictive on the html, css and javascript. They only allow some part of the language to work.
You can check these two resources to see what you can/or cannot do in each email client:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_email_clients

In general Javascript is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

I may say it's theoretically possible, but **highly not recommended**: everything depends on mail agent (for example software on pc does not support JS at all). Most of them are blocking both inline and include JS.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

How client application will render html mails does not have a standard.

See here: http://www.email-standards.org/acid-test/

An html email should always be as-it-is with a static layout.

And JS ist not supported by normal clients. maybe some will support but it should not!